# JScrollPanes, JTextAreas, and maximum sizes

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout, sizing

*Context*: In a flashcard application, I have a view for a `CardData` (a data structure representing one side of a flashcard). It has, in its most basic form, a `String text`. The view (known as `CardDataView`) consists of the `text` in an uneditable `JTextArea` inside a `JScrollPane`.

At one point, I need to line up (vertically) a bunch of these `CardDataView`s, so I put them in a vertical `Box`.

Here's the problem: when I expand the window from it's "preferred" size (as determined by `pack`) and then size it back down, the JScrollPane adds a horizontal scroll bar and allows me to scroll horizontally in  the text field. Essentially, **it's sizing up the text area when it shouldn't be.**

Here's my code (stripped down and simplified):

```
public class DebugTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CardDataView cdv = new CardDataView(new CardData(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet filler filler filler"));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(cdv), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class CardData {
    private String text; // text on the card

    /*
     * NOTE: This class has been simplified for SSCCE purposes. It's not really
     * just a String field in production; rather, it has an image and other
     * properties.
     */

    public CardData(String text) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}

class CardDataView extends Box {
    private JTextArea txtrText; // the text area for the text

    /*
     * NOTE: As with CardData, this class has been simplified. It's not just a
     * JTextArea; it's also an ImageView (custom class; works fine), among other
     * things.
     */

    public CardDataView(CardData data) {
        super(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        txtrText = new JTextArea();
        txtrText.setLineWrap(true);
        txtrText.setRows(3);
        txtrText.setEditable(false);
        txtrText.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtrText);
        add(scrollPane);
        txtrText.setText(data.getText());
    }
}
```

Now, something that *really* confuses me (unless I'm going about it wrong) is that if I essentially inline the data and view classes, by just creating a text area with text and a scroll pane (even with setting the same number of rows, same wrap settings, etc.), it behaves as expected. What could be happening?

Concerns:
- All imports are in order.
- If you're wondering why `CardLayoutView` is a `Box`: in production, it has more than just a text box. The same error happens when it's a `JPanel` and I `setLayout` instead of `super`.
- The same glitch happens if I don't use the `CardData` class at all (and set the text area's text manually).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "inline the data and view classes"

Comment: Had you tried using the `GridBagLayout` with `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL/NONE` as the `gridBagLayoutObject.fill` value, instead of opting for the `BoxLayout` inside your `CardDataView` Class ? Since you adding this class to the `CENTER` of the `JFrame` and here `BorderLayout` doesn't respect the `preferredSize()` for the `CENTER` component IMHO. Instead try to add this to the `JPanel` and then put this `JPanel` at the `CENTER` of the `JFrame`

Comment: Removing the root scrollpane your example runs fine. Now I would follow nIcEcOw's suggestion to use a GridBagLayout rather than the BoxLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comment to answer :

Use `GridBagLayout` with `GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL/NONE` as the `gridBagLayoutObject.fill` value, instead of `BoxLayout`. Since when adding components to the `CENTER` of the `JFrame`, `BorderLayout` never respects the `preferredSize()` for the `CENTER` component. Hence try to add your stuff to a `JPanel` and then put this `JPanel` at the `CENTER` of the `JFrame`.